# Why isn't my text color white in this material UI toolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My toolbar is showing a color of purple which is correct, but the text is black so it's unreadable. It's my understanding that the color of the text should change based on the color of the background that it's on in Material-UI. Maybe I'm really misunderstanding how to use it, but hopefully you can clear this up for me.

Here's the component that I'm using.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import ToolbarGroup from 'material-ui/Toolbar/ToolbarGroup';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import customTheme from '../UIThemes';
class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(customTheme)}>
        <div>
          <Toolbar className="mdc-toolbar--fixed">
            <ToolbarGroup>
              Am I white?
            </ToolbarGroup>
            <ToolbarGroup>
              Two
            </ToolbarGroup>
            <ToolbarGroup>
            Three
            </ToolbarGroup>
          </Toolbar>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the theme that I made custom based on what material ui had on their site on how a theme is made.

```js
import {
  fullWhite,
} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import { fade } from 'material-ui/utils/colorManipulator';
import spacing from 'material-ui/styles/spacing';

export default {
  spacing,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  borderRadius: 2,
  palette: {
    primary1Color: '#3f51b5',
    primary2Color: '#002984',
    primary3Color: '#757de8',
    accent1Color: '#673ab7',
    accent2Color: '#320b86',
    accent3Color: '#9a67ea',
    textColor: '#FFFFFF',
    secondaryTextColor: fade(fullWhite, 0.7),
    alternateTextColor: '#303030',
    canvasColor: '#303030',
    borderColor: fade(fullWhite, 0.3),
    disabledColor: fade(fullWhite, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: fade(fullWhite, 0.12),
    clockCircleColor: fade(fullWhite, 0.12),
  },
};
```

I'm brand new to material ui and am using it through doing yarn add material-ui if that makes any difference.

Does anyone have any idea why the color of the text inside of the Toolbar groups aren't changing to white, or am i really missing something? I'm assuming that everything that's wrapped inside of the MuiThemeProvider should receive my custom style settings i linked.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using material-ui 0.x and not material-ui@next? The v1 beta is now pretty stable and includes a ton of breaking changes from the previous version, so it might not be worth the time to learn 0.x.

Comment: I just checked, and the problem you're having with text color in the toolbar should be fixed in the v1-beta (that is, the text color will change automatically with the background).

Comment: i didn't realize they'd keep something up that doesn't work. Quite frustrating. Thanks for the heads up though, I'll go to the v1 beta